# How to apend subject line in email sent on google form submit using script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have been able to use this code I got from spreadsheet.dev and its working flawlessly!  It emails me all the questions/responses that were submitted.  Now, I am trying to tweak it slightly to add the account number that is entered by the user filling out the form (question 3 if that matters), to the end of the subject line.

I have tried some of the suggestions I have found, but keep getting typeerrors whenever I try to tweak the code.  The code below is my working code, it doesn't have any of my attempted tweaks.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
// Restrict the script's authorization
// to the form it is bound to.
//@OnlyCurrentDoc

// Create a form submit installable trigger
// using Apps Script.
function createFormSubmitTrigger() {

  // Get the form object.
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();

  // Since we know this project should only have a single trigger
  // we'll simply check if there are more than 0 triggers. If yes,
  // we'll assume this function was already run so we won't create
  // a trigger.
  var currentTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  if(currentTriggers.length > 0)
    return;
  
  // Create a trigger that will run the onFormSubmit function
  // whenever the form is submitted.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("onFormSubmit").forForm(form).onFormSubmit().create();
}
// A function that is called by the form submit
// trigger. The parameter e contains information
// submitted by the user.
function onFormSubmit(e) {
 
  // Get the response that was submitted.
  var formResponse = e.response;

  // Get the items (i.e., responses to various questions)
  // that were submitted.
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

  // Create a variable emailBody to store the body
  // of the email notification to be sent.
  var emailBody = "New Service Input:\n\n";

  // Put together the email body by appending all the
  // questions & responses to the variable emailBody.
  itemResponses.forEach(function(itemResponse) {
    var title = itemResponse.getItem().getTitle();
    var response = itemResponse.getResponse();
    emailBody += title + "\n" + response + "\n\n";
  });

  // Send the email notification using the
  // sendEmail() function.
  sendEmail(emailBody);
}

// A function that sends the email
// notification.
function sendEmail(emailBody) {
  MailApp.sendEmail("test@email.com", "New Service Input", emailBody);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Script:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
 
  // Get the response that was submitted.
  var formResponse = e.response;

  // Get the items (i.e., responses to various questions)
  // that were submitted.
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

  //Added this to access the response from Item 3
  var numAcc = itemResponses[2].getResponse(); 
  

  // Create a variable emailBody to store the body
  // of the email notification to be sent.
  var emailBody = "New Service Input:\n\n";

  // Put together the email body by appending all the
  // questions & responses to the variable emailBody.
  itemResponses.forEach(function(itemResponse) {
    var title = itemResponse.getItem().getTitle();
    var response = itemResponse.getResponse();
    emailBody += title + "\n" + response + "\n\n";
  });

  // Send the email notification using the
  // sendEmail() function.
  sendEmail(emailBody,numAcc); //added paramater to pass the numAcc Var
}

// A function that sends the email
// notification.
function sendEmail(emailBody,numAcc) { //added paramater to pass the numAcc Var
  MailApp.sendEmail("alexa@devopstraining.club", "New Service Input " + numAcc, emailBody);

}
```

You are already storing the item responses, from here you can use add the `index[2]` so you can target specifically the third response. You can then store this in a var which you can use to pass to the `sendEmail` function.

**As shown above**, I have added the `var numAcc = itemResponses[2].getResponse();`  to access Item 3,
then add a parameter to `sendEmail(emailBody,numAcc)` function to pass it.

### Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi! As a general rule in StackOverflow, if your concern is solved please accept an answer which works best for you by clicking the check mark beside the answer. This is to let other members from the community with the same concern as yours know that the issue resolved. [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)